# Why does 64-bit GCC warn about converting a const int to long unsigned int when allocating an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, 64-bit

I have a file test.cpp that looks like this:

```
void f(const int n) {
  unsigned char *a=new unsigned char[n];
  delete[] a;
}

int main() {
  f(4);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it in 64-bit GCC with the `-Wsign-conversion` flag produces the warning:

```
test.cpp:2:39: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘const int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
```

(line 2 is the line in which `new` is called). It seems strange to me that GCC should give this warning about allocating an array, but the following things are even stranger:

1. Replacing the offending line with `unsigned char *a=new unsigned char[(long unsigned int)n];` does not get rid of the warning, nor does using `static_cast<long unsigned int>()`.
2. No warning is produced if `f` is defined with the signature `void f(T n)`, where `T` is

   1. any non-const, signed or unsigned integer type of any size, or
   2. a signed 64-bit integer type.

   It does however produce warnings when `T` is any const signed integer type smaller than 64-bits.

Bearing in mind that I'm on a 64-bit (Linux) machine, why does the sign-conversion warning care about the constness and size of `n` in this case, and why doesn't type casting fix the problem?

*Note 1: I wanted to test this under another compiler, but the Comeau site is down, and I don't have access to any other compilers, so I can't tell if this is standard-compliant behaviour, or a GCC bug.*

*Note 2: test.cpp is a minimal example of a problem from a "real" C++ file that I have in which the best way for me to get rid of the warning was to surround the offending line with:*

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-conversion"
// ...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: It's warning you that if you call `f(-1)` you might be surprised.

Comment: You cannot allocate a negatively sized array, so it is probably converting `n` to an unsigned value before performing the allocation. Change your parameter to just `unsigned int n` and see if the warning disappears.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, but why does it not warn in other similar cases?

Comment: @PeteBecker - That doesn't explain why it produces no warnings when I change f's signature to void f(int n).

Comment: I suspect it's converting to `size_t`, which is probably a typedef for `long unsigned int`.

Comment: @Ose - You ask why the compiler warns you about some common errors but not all, less common, bad code?

Comment: It's purely a "knee jerk" warning -- has nothing to do with the `new` op itself, but merely with the conversion that is implied from converting "n" to the "parameter type" of the `new` op -- you'd get the same warning calling a method with the same parm type.  And it's warning that you may lose "significance" (in a big way) on the signed -> unsigned conversion.

Comment: The reason it occurs only for `const` likely has to do with the parameter passing conventions of that compiler.  Likely most ints are widened to 64 bits, so conversion int -> long is really 64-bit -> long, but apparently const values are treated differently.  These things can get pretty screwy.

Comment: @HotLicks - that's interesting. Do you know if there's any documentation of these GCC parameter passing conventions?

Comment: I would expect the static_cast to fail because you can't use static_cast to cast away constness.

Comment: @Ose - Haven't a clue.  I'm sure there's some documentation somewhere, but it may be very cryptic text in a very obscure location.

Comment: @BoPersson - I'm asking whether or not there is an interesting technical explanation for why the compiler treats the superficially similar cases I've described differently, to make sure I have not misunderstood something fundamental about the C++ type system.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - oh yes, good point. I'm about to go on holiday, but when I return, I'll see if static_cast<const long unsigned int> works. I'll be surprised if it does though, given that the C-style cast doesn't work.

Comment: @Ose - I believe the reason simply is that the compiler team has experienced, or received bug reports for, some conversion problems. They then decided to add warnings for things people often get wrong.

Comment: @Ose: The issue has been reported before a few times. This is just a quirk of GCC compiler, something you have to live with. I'd guess that the authors of the compiler understood now useless this warning is in some contexts and made a deliberate effort to suppress it in such contexts. But they didn't get them all, which is why you see this warning appear so inconsistently.

Comment: @AndreyT thanks, that sounds like a candidate for an acceptable answer. Do you have a link to a bug report or GCC changelog to back it up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little flaky on the details, but it seems to me that the issue is actually in sign *extension* (since size_t is most likely an unsigned long on your system). Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(const int n) {
      unsigned long int b = static_cast<long unsigned int>(n);
      printf ("0x%llx == %lld\n", b, b);
}

int main() {
      unsigned long int c = 1;
      c <<= 31;
      printf ("0x%llx == %lld \n", c, c);
      f(c);
      return 0;
}
```

it prints:

```
0x80000000 == 2147483648
0xffffffff80000000 == -2147483648
```

Note that I intentionally picked a value that means a negative as an int, but not as a long. The first print should actually be 0x0000000080000000. If I picked a simple -1, it would still get sign-extended to long as a -1, but this one gives something completely different.

Of course if you explicitly cast it to an unsigned you also get something else, but my guess is that the compiler is more worried about the implicit conversions (the up-convert to 64bit in this case) that you're more likely to miss ("what could possibly go wrong with *more* bits?")

Another hint it's the upconvert that's bugging us (if not, i'll be happy to hear another explanation):

```
int main() {
    int n = 1;
    const long int a = static_cast<long int> (n);
    const int b = static_cast<int> (n);
    char* ap = new char [a];
    char* bp = new char [b];
}
```

This complains only on b

```
test.cpp: In function ?int main()?:
test.cpp:8:27: warning: conversion to ?long unsigned int? from ?const int? may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
     char* bp = new char [b];
```

so we've ruled out the option that function arguments passing is to blame

Now, if I may further speculate, perhaps that warning is specific to memory allocations (note that you don't get it from simply casting n to long), because the compiler would have wanted to do some allocation magic given a constant size. Imagine the shock it got when it saw what you're trying to do.

Comment: None of this explains why the compiler doesn't issue the warning when the array size parameter is non-const. E.g. adding `char* np=new char[n];` to your second code fragment does not produce an extra warning.

Answer (score 0):

const int is a signed value, You are casting a signed value to unsigned value.
So the compiler is generating a warning that in some cases, this conversion might result in wrong calculations.

Comment: `int` is also a signed type. However, as OP stated, if the parameter is declared with type `int`, there's no warning. It is the `const` specifically that seems to trigger it. This is the key point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

well its converting for you but its warning you that the conversion it is making will change the sign of the value it is changing otherwise you might automatically lose some Value and bugs could resulytt its just saying you are
 casting a int to a unsigned int this may change the value of the sign normally if i passed int to the array bounds operator it would not warn like you like this

try tururning of the conversion flag that you have on and see if it still does this the flag is whats causing the warning because it is the thing doing the conversion

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this will have to do with the way integer literals are handled: When you write

```
int myArray[10];
```

the number ten is converted to a signed integer, and the compiler should never complain on that for obvious reasons. So, I guess, there will be an exception in the type checking for the signed integer. When you use a const int, gcc seems to consider this a different type for which the integer exception does not apply, hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The TL;DR: if it represents the size of something, make it a `std::size_t`.

The problem is that array `new` takes as its size parameter a value of type `std::size_t`, which is guaranteed by the standard to be an unsigned integral type, as evidenced by the compiler’s complaint of conversion to `long unsigned int`. That’s where the signed-unsigned conversion is taking place, and the (IMO) correct way to fix the problem is simply to give the parameter `n` of function `f` type `std::size_t`. This suppresses the warning at least with GCC 4.6 for x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: That doesn't explain why no warning is produced under the conditions listed in point 2 of my question. Also, what does "TL;DR" stand for?

Comment: @Ose I’m not sure. I think the best explanation is @AndreyT’s, that it’s just a (possibly intentional) quirk of GCC’s type analysis. “TL;DR” stands for “Too Long; Don’t [or Didn’t] Read.”

Answer (score 0):

The compiler warns, because the sign might change when converting to an unsigned value.

> 1 .  Replacing the offending line with unsigned char *a=new unsigned char[(long unsigned int)n]; does not get rid of the warning, nor does using static_cast().

The problem of sign conversion persists, you just made it explicit. My guess is, that it's still not explicit enough for the compiler to believe you. It still believes you declared `n` a *signed* `const int` for a reason!

> 2 .  No warning is produced if f is defined with the signature void f(T n), where T is
>
> > 1 . any non-const, signed or unsigned integer type of any size

If `n` is non-const, there *might* be code between the beginning of the function and the conversion, that ensured that n was positive, like `n = (long unsigned int)(n);`. It seems that the compiler is giving you the benefit of doubt in this case, and therefore doesn't warn. When it *is* declared const, the compiler knows for sure that it is dealing with an `int` and warns.

I admit, my explanations don't sound like something g++ would typically do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the signature of your function - the compiler would do implicit conversion when you pass the **constant literal 4** to a function with corresponding argument declared as **const int**.

You can try replacing the argument type as **const unsigned int** to get rid of the warning message.

Answer (score 0):

`std::size_t` is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting. Programs that use other types, such as unsigned int, for array indexing may fail on, e.g. 64-bit systems when the index exceeds `UINT_MAX` or if it relies on 32-bit modular arithmetic. [click here to read more about std::size_t and 64-bit systems](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but this doesn't answer either of the two questions that I asked. The best answer so far was given by AnT in the comments below the question.